# MongoDb - Query collection by aggregating the product of a sub-set of values

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a collection:

```
[
    {
        _id: product_a,
        values: [
            { id: 1, value: 0 },
            { id: 2, value: 1 },
            { id: 3, value: 2 },
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: product_b,
        values: [
            { id: 1, value: 1 },
            { id: 2, value: 2 },
            { id: 3, value: 2 },
        ]
    },
    // etc ...
];
```

Is there any way to query this collection by aggregating the product of a sub-set of "values"?

If I query { values: [ 1, 3 ] }, I would get something like:

```
[
    {
        _id: product_a,
        result: 0 // since 0 * 2 = 0
    },
    {
        _id: product_b,
        result: 2 // since 1 * 2 = 2
    },
    // etc ...
];
```

Comment: is your schema fixed or could you store values as {"id1":"value","id2":"value"...} instead? i.e. are your id values known upfront?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with the schema the way you have it using 2.2 aggregation framework.  Note that this would be a lot simpler if the id/value pairs were stored with id as key.

Your aggregation [pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-pipeline):

```
[
    {
        "$unwind" : "$values"
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "values.id" : {
                "$in" : [
                    1,
                    3
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : 1,
            "val1" : {
                "$cond" : [
                    {
                        "$eq" : [
                            "$values.id",
                            1
                        ]
                    },
                    "$values.value",
                    -1
                ]
            },
            "val3" : {
                "$cond" : [
                    {
                        "$eq" : [
                            "$values.id",
                            3
                        ]
                    },
                    "$values.value",
                    -1
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "val1" : {
                "$max" : "$val1"
            },
            "val3" : {
                "$max" : "$val3"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : 1,
            "result" : {
                "$multiply" : [
                    "$val1",
                    "$val3"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Note that the last step would do the job if the structure of your document was:
`{_id: "product_x", values: [ {id1: value}, {id2: value} etc. ]}`

Now run the query from the shell with:
`> db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)`

Or from your code via `db.runCommand({"aggregate":"collection","pipeline":[...]})`

Comment: Thanks Asya, that looks fantastic! Guess I will have to use a Development Release version of Mongo to have this functionality, right?